# Angular2 html binding (html contain variable)

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have theHtmlString variable and bind as follow is correct:

```
<div [innerHTML]="theHtmlString">
</div>
```

But theHtmlString variable has contain some orther variable:

```
theHtmlString = "<input [(ngModel)]='value'/>";
```

How bind HTML for it?

Comment: what @GunterZochbauer said, and as a result, you'll need to use [`DynamicComponentLoader`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html) to implement this.

Comment: But i have not get data from dynamic component loader

Answer (score 3):

Angular doesn't process HTML added this way. It doesn't resolve bindings nor instantiate components or directives. It's passed to the browser as-is.

Comment: So is it impossible to accomplish this?

Comment: I wouldn't say impossible, but not plain simple either ;-). You can create a component at runtime like explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960 and add this component instead. There is a ready-to-use library that makes it easier to dynamically create components (don't remember the name). Currently this is not compatible with AoT though.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like that in the template:

```
<div [innerHTML]="value + 'abc ...'">
</div>
```

Otherwise you can use curly brackets this way into your expression...